# Java - Does casting a variable to a type instantiate the type's class?

Tags: java, casting

Hi Stackoverflow Community

I started learning Java and am working my way through some rather difficult code. I am wondering whether casting a variable to an Object Type is enough to instantiate that object?

During the code I noticed how one method casts an object called **pastaVariable** to **ArrayType** inside a method's arguments.

See here:

```
public ComplexType getIndexPredicateTypeForArray(ArrayType pastaVariable) {
        final Type baseType = pastaVariable.getBaseType();
        return baseType;
    }
```

The method **getBaseType()** is defined inside the class **ArrayType.java** which looks like this:

```
public class ArrayType extends Type {

    private final Type          baseType;
    private final Type          parent;

    ArrayType(String name, Type baseType, Type parent) {
        super(name);
        this.parent = parent;
        this.baseType = baseType;
    }

    public Type getBaseType() {
        return baseType;
    }
....
```

Since the variable **baseType** in **ArrayType.java** is declared in the **ArrayType class's constructor** I am wondering where this constructor is being triggered?

I can't find the ArrayType's class constructor be called anywhere else in the code.

So is it possible that the **ArrayType constructor** is triggered when we cast **pastaVariable** to **ArrayType** as the argument for the **getIndexPredicateTypeForArray** method?

Comment: I don't think you have posted full code here, it's just confusing when you refer to some method which is not present in code.

Comment: Thanks @Mritunjay. Adjusted the code accordingly.

Comment: Where do you call `getIndexPredicateTypeForArray` from? With what value?

Comment: First of all in Java, Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference; it passes them by value. So yes, pastaVariable when passed to method getIndexPredicateTypeForArray then it calls the constructor. Refer to http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you would call the method `getIndexPredicateTypeForArray` from. You would pass a instance of `ArrayType` to this method as the only argument. That instance when created is responsible for calling the constructor of ArrayType or defining the fields declared within.l the class.